# using classes instead of primitives in java

Tags: java, class

consider that we want to define an array of integers.

we have two options:

1: `Integer[] a=new Integer[5];`

2:`int[] a=new int[5]`

so we can always use the first one because it is a class and it has useful methods.

so why should we use the second one?

Comment: What "useful methods" does `Integer` have?

Comment: Wrapper classes have unnecessary overhead, so use them only when you have to; for example in `Arrays.asList(anIntegerArray)`.